# Нужна ли запятая в «больше чем»?

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

Предложение:

> Мне не нужно быть ей больше, чем другом, чтобы защитить её, если подобное повторится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не ставится: Мне не нужно быть ей **больше чем другом**, чтобы защитить её, если подобное повторится.

Розенталь: [§ 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)

Внутри сочетаний (не) больше чем, (не) меньше чем, (не) раньше чем, (не) позже чем и т. п., **если они не содержат сравнения**, запятая не ставится: Вы были для меня больше чем другом.

Но: запятая ставится **при наличии сравнения или сопоставления**: Работает не меньше, чем другие; Гостей оказалось меньше, чем ожидали; Страдали от холода больше, чем от голода; Больше, чем от физической боли, он страдал от мысли, что он теперь инвалид (Газ.); Больше, чем что-либо другое, больному нужен покой; Сипягин волновался гораздо более, чем его гость (Т.);

Comment: Спасибо. Я правило на Грамоте многократно читал, но там не было столь удачного примера, как по вашей ссылке, поэтому и впал в ступор.